# Submit then close a Form

Tags: javascript, html

What is the best way to close a form's webpage after the submit button is clicked? I want the form to post then close and for the life of me I cant find a good way to do this. I guess if it comes down to it I can do an ajax call then call window.close() when the ajax call completes.

Comment: when you say "close", is this a popup?

Comment: Most browsers won't allow JavaScript to close the window unless it was opened from JavaScript in the first place. So yes, an Ajax call followed by `window.close()` should work if you opened the window from JS...

Comment: put the form inside a div, and call show() / hide() methods (with the div-id) that you can implement either in jQuery or in JS: http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/

Comment: If you attempt to close my main web browser, I will add you to the DOS sites I will never visit again. Maybe you give us some hint as to WHY you want to close the browser - perhaps you are nervous that the users re-submit the forms? Then we can assist you fix your site rather than fix your users

Comment: Yes it's a modal popup I have to call with window.showModalDialog(). No I'm not closing the main page lol. It's just a modal popup for a login and I'm using the current login form for this page. The form submits then usually redirects to a return URL. when I tried making the return URL as javascript:window.close() the browser isn't happy with that. I can't use the jQuery solution proposed by alfasin because that won't stop the execution of javascript like showModalDialog will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using jQuery...

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serializeArray());
    window.close();
});
```

Comment: I'll try this out and let you know